# Separate values in PHP

Tags: php

To pass a group of checked checkbox values from a modal to a parent form, I send them to a hidden field.

This works well and is currently, as an example, returned in the format below

```
<input type="hidden" value="Mon, Wed, Sat" name="days">
```

What I need is to get an apostrophe seperated list in an array like this,

```
$days = array('Mon', 'Wed', 'Sat');   // currently static
```

from my hidden field here..

```
$days = Input::get('days'); // days selected in checkboxes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use explode method()

> explode() Returns an array of strings, each of which is a substring of
>   string formed by splitting it on boundaries formed by the string
>   delimiter.

[Refrence](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

```
 $string ="Mon, Wed, Sat";
 $strngarray =  explode(',', string );
```

In your case

```
$days = explode(', ', Input::get('days');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `explode()`:

```
$days = explode(', ', Input::get('days'));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Answer (score 1):

The function [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) should do this in php.

```
$values = 'value1, value2, value3';
$arrayOfValues = explode(', ', $values);
print_r($arrayOfValues);
```